# PieChart and legending issues

Tags: color, legending, charts

I'm trying to do some bar charts and pie charts in Mathematica, but I can't figure out how to make the legend colors correspond to the actual colors on the charts. I'm running

```
10.4.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)
```

The code that I've got is:

```
PieChart[
 {1, 2, 3, 4},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{angle}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][angle]],
 ChartLegends -> {"This", "is", "the wrong", "color"}
 ]
```

What I get is the following:

[image]

This persists for `BarChart` as well, I haven't tried any others, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the legending options in general.

Any idea how to make the `ChartLegends` behave according to the `ColorFunction`? I've been trying to go through the documentation, but it's not exactly as detailed as I'd like it to be.

Comment: `Function[{angle}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][angle]]` is in most cases the same as `ColorData["DarkRainbow"]`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow"` instead of `ColorFunction`.

`ChartStyle` determines the list of colours to be used.

`ColorFunction` determines how to compute the colour from each value.  Two pie slices of the same size will have the same colour when you use `ColorFunction`.  I think that in this situation, it makes no sense to have a separate legend entry for each slice.

However, if you still decide to use `ColorFunction`, you can use an explicit `SwatchLegend` specification in `ChartLegends`, with an explicit (manually computed) list of colours.

Comment: So basically, if I have some data in the form of ``{labels,values}`` that I want to plot using ``BarChart`` or ``PieChart``, and use the legending according to the color on the plot, I should do something like:
``ColorFunction->Function[whatever],...,ChartLegends->SwatchLegend[Function[whatever]/@{scaledValues},labels]``?

Comment: @blueshift Not unless you want to colour the bars according to their height (in which case the use of a swatch legend is IMO misleading—a bar legend would fit better).