# Problem with PieChart ColorFunction and GrayLevel

Tags: color, charts

Related: [PieChart and legending issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138107/piechart-and-legending-issues)

I have the following list:

```
   list = {{"Nordrhein-Westfalen", 
   0.19148936170212766`}, {"Baden-Württemberg", 
   0.1466359976998275`}, {"Niedersachsen", 
   0.07245543415756182`}, {"Bayern", 
   0.1311098332374928`}, {"Rheinland-Pfalz", 
   0.05117883841288096`}, {"Schleswig-Holstein", 
   0.03220241518113859`}, {"Brandenburg", 
   0.08970672800460035`}, {"Thüringen", 
   0.0097757331799885`}, {"Sachsen-Anhalt", 
   0.006900517538815411`}, {"Hessen", 
   0.09200690051753882`}, {"Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", 
   0.010350776308223116`}, {"Berlin", 
   0.08338125359401956`}, {"Saarland", 
   0.014951121334100058`}, {"Bremen", 
   0.011500862564692352`}, {"Hamburg", 0.05635422656699252`}}
```

No problem making a colored PieChart

```
PieChart[Last /@ list, ChartLegends -> (First /@ list)]
```

gives:

[image]

While playing around I tried:

```
    PieChart[Last /@ list, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
 ChartLegends -> (First /@ list)]
```

and got:

[image]

O.K. its ugly but the legends are not appropriately colored. Can anyone tell my, why?

Remark (2018-03-26): I didn't have seen this as a pure duplicate (- and still do not. The question for me is that given an explicit `ColorFunction` this is taken to color the pieces of the chart but **not** the Legends. For me this is not very logical. When specifying a colorfunction I expect that this is not only used to color the Pie but also the legends.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{"Nordrhein-Westfalen", 0.19148936170212766`}, {"Baden-Württemberg", 
    0.1466359976998275`}, {"Niedersachsen", 0.07245543415756182`}, {"Bayern", 
    0.1311098332374928`}, {"Rheinland-Pfalz", 
    0.05117883841288096`}, {"Schleswig-Holstein", 
    0.03220241518113859`}, {"Brandenburg", 
    0.08970672800460035`}, {"Thüringen", 
    0.0097757331799885`}, {"Sachsen-Anhalt", 
    0.006900517538815411`}, {"Hessen", 
    0.09200690051753882`}, {"Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", 
    0.010350776308223116`}, {"Berlin", 0.08338125359401956`}, {"Saarland", 
    0.014951121334100058`}, {"Bremen", 0.011500862564692352`}, {"Hamburg", 
    0.05635422656699252`}};
```

I don't know the cause of the problem; however, you can use

```
PieChart[Legended[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ list, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

For a clearer `Tooltip`

```
PieChart[Tooltip[Legended[#[[2]], #[[1]]], Column@#] & /@ list, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```